# Angular conditional class gets overridden

Tags: html, angular, css

I have 2 CSS classes, `date-today` is conditionally applied to an element but it doesn't work because date overrides it.

```
.date-today {
    color: red;
}

.date {
    color: green;
}
```

Componenet:

```
[ngClass]="{ 'date-today': date.isToday() }"
```

How can I get the `date-today` class to override `date`?

Comment: Can you provide the complete html code you have used and also your ts that has ```date.isToday()```??

Comment: why dont you just remove the dash and write the class as `dateToday` ? That way it shouldn't override it...

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of css rules to prevent override(It calls [`specificty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity))

```css
/*date first*/
.date {
    color: green;
}
/*date-today second*/
.date-today {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="date date-today">
date
</div>
```

**See whats happen when orders of rules change:**

```css
.date-today {
    color: red;
}
.date {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="date date-today">
date
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `color: red;` to `color: red!important;` but maybe you could **move** your `date` class setting into the `[ngClass]` and place it in the order like below

```
[ngClass]="{ 
    'date': !date.isToday(),
    'date date-today': date.isToday()
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
<p [class.date]="!today" [class.date-today]="today">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<button (click)="today = true">today</button>
```